# Installation problem while downloading WGCNA package in R

Tags: r

I am trying to download the WGCNA package and get the following error.

I followed the instructions from  https://horvath.genetics.ucla.edu/html/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/

```
install.packages("WGCNA")
```

I get the following in particular "Warning in install.packages : installation of package ‘WGCNA’ had non-zero exit status".

```
> install.packages("WGCNA")
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of C/C++/Fortran: ‘WGCNA’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources? (Yes/no/cancel) Yes
installing the source package ‘WGCNA’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/WGCNA_1.68.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1166156 bytes (1.1 MB)
==================================================
downloaded 1.1 MB

* installing *source* package ‘WGCNA’ ...
** package ‘WGCNA’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘WGCNA’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/WGCNA’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘WGCNA’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/4_/d5qjrrgj25j2v73z3jwcyj600000gn/T/RtmpaRft6B/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Do you have XCode installed?

Comment: No I don't. Is it required?

Comment: Yes, since you're installing from source. See [#4 of the FAQs on WGCNA](https://horvath.genetics.ucla.edu/html/CoexpressionNetwork/Rpackages/WGCNA/faq.html). You can find instructions re: getting XCode setup on the [Mac OS section here](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486498-Package-Development-Prerequisites).

Comment: Just finished installing Xcode. I still get the same message.

Answer (score 0):

Just installing Xcode does not install all command line tools. You can install them in the terminal by running:

> xcode-select --install

It fixed it on my machine.